Tooltip renders outside of viewport even when there is sufficient space on the opposite side?
I have run into an issue with highcharts tooltip positioning, where the tooltip gets rendered below the point, partially outside of the viewport even when there is sufficient space to show it on the top. I am not using the positioner function. I am having a reversed Y axis and the outside option set to true for the tooltip. This adds a scrollbar, whenever we hover on a point that is positioned near the bottom of the page.

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep',
            'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
        ],
    },
    yAxis: {
        reversed: true
    },
    tooltip:{
      outside:true,
      useHTML:true,
      padding:60,
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1,
            95.6, 54.4
        ]
    }]
});

Fiddle

Note: Please set the height of the viewport to 435px to observe this issue

Hi, do you mean the bottom scrollbar that shows for a half second when moving tooltip?

@magdalena, yes, the scrollbar remains as long as you keep hovering over the point.

I’m not sure if I got the same effect. In my case, scroll only shows a very short time at the bottom. Can you confirm if it's related to the bottom scroll? Also, which browser do you use to get this effect?

Please try this,
tooltip:{
  outside:false,
}


I need the outside option to be enabled since we have small charts (setting outside to false will force it render within the small area of the chart), however I dont want it to render out of the viewport, when there is space on the opposite side ( above the point ). This happens only when the chart is at the bottom of the page, and we hover on a point that is close to the bottom.
